# Adding properties to function, object and prototype

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Lets say I have this function:

```
function myFunc () {
    this.property1 = 10;
}
var myObject = new myFunc();
```

Now lets say I want to add a new property to it.

```
myFunc.newProperty = "New"; 
myObject.newProperty = "New";
myFunc.prototype.newProperty = "New";
```

What is difference between these aproaches? And which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**

```
myFunc.newProperty = "New";
```

Because the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) itself is an object, you just create a new property on it. It may be useful you if you work directly with the **Function object**.

**Approach 2**

```
myObject.newProperty = "New";
```

On a new instance of the `myFunc` constructor, you **create an own property**. Useful when you need to modify a single instance, but don't want to modify the class itself with `newProperty`.
Any new instances created with `new myFunc()` will not inherit or contain the `newProperty`.

**Approach 3**

```
myFunc.prototype.newProperty = "New";
```

If you **modify the constructor prototype**, then the created objects will inherit this property. Useful when you need any existing or new object created with `new myFunc()` to inherit the `newProperty`.

Which one to use depends on the task. The points **2** and **3** are commonly used.

Comment: good answer. Just a point with **Approach 3** - what I inferred from the answer is that *only* new objects will inherit any property added to the constructor prototype, but in fact existing objects will also inherit the property too - it may be my misinterpreting your answer, but I just wanted to point that out

Answer (score 1):

`myFunct` is Constructor function(in fact every function in JS can be used as Constructor), when used with `new`  this function creates a new object.

now you want to add new properties to object:

1) want to add new property to already created myObject

```
myObject.newProperty = "New";
```

2) want to add new property to every object created from `myFunc`

```
function myFunc () {
    this.property1 = 10;
    this.newProperty = "New"; 
}
```

3) want to have new property in all the object already created from `myFunc` and it should be a property of parent object(so that only one copy is available) for all the newly created object from `myFunc`

```
myFunc.prototype.newProperty = "New";
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you are doing

```
myFunc.newProperty = "New";
```

this property is is treated as private Property of myFunc so even if you make some instance of myFunc you will not able to access.

Same in the case of

```
myObject.newProperty = "New";
```

when you are making it its treated a private property of  myObject so outside of myObject you can not access it.

And when you are doing

```
myFunc.prototype.newProperty = "New";
```

You can access newProperty from all the instance of myFunc.

Which is good which is bad i cant say its all requirement